# Python 3 - List to dictionary. Sort by words

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I've got a list which looks like this:

```
['Data', '2017-10-12', 'Nr', 'lekcji', '6', 'Nauczyciel', 'Name', 'Nothing', 'Rodzaj', 'sprawdzian', 'Przedmiot', 'Math', 'Opis', 'This', 'is', 'just', 'a', 'test.', 'Data', 'dodania', '2017-10-01', '18:12:31']
```

And I want to convert it to list which some keywords. Here is the result which I want to get:

```
{'Data': '2017-10-12', 'Nr lekcji': '6', 'Nauczyciel': 'Name Nothing', 'Rodzaj': 'sprawdzian', 'Przedmiot': 'Math', 'Opis': 'This is just a test.', 'Data dodania': '2017-10-01 18:21:32'}
```

Is it possible ? Thanks for help!

EDIT

base string:

```
Data
2017-10-12


Nr lekcji
6


Nauczyciel
Name Nothing


Rodzaj
sprawdzian


Przedmiot
Math


Opis
This is just a test.


Data dodania

                                        2017-10-01 18:12:31
```

Comment: how to decide when to group the items and when not to group them?

Comment: How did you get your first list to start with? It looks like it's come from somewhere and been overzealously split on whitespace...

Comment: Yes it is possible, but to make a code snippet that you can repeat more times we need to understand how you got the list in the first place.

Comment: `Data` is always this format: `year-month-day`, `Nr lekcji` is always number 1-9, `Nauczyciel` has got always 2 words for example `Ben` `Smith`, `Przedmiot` has got only 1 word. `Data dodania` is date format for example: `2017-10-01 18:21:32`. `Rodzaj` has got from 1 to 2. Problem is with `Opis`, because it has unlimited words.

Comment: Can you share with us the raw data, before it transferred to a list? I assume the list has created by executing `split()` on it.

Comment: @JonClements I scrapped if from website and I removed whitespaces with this: `mylist = [e for e in scrapped_text.replace('\n', ' ').split(' ') if e != '']`

Comment: @xaos_xv share the scrapped_text before you did your manipulation. thank you

Comment: @xaos_xv that looks a more reasonable of text to work with... however, if you're scraping from a site, isn't there some structure to the page that already separates those elements - are they in different columns in a table, or in paragraph tags or...

Comment: @AntonvBR Check my edit.

Comment: @xaos_xv Now we are talking! This is what you should have posted from the start.

Comment: Okay... so looks like it's one line for what it is, followed by some stuff (either always N many lines or whatever) - so break that up accordingly instead of reconstructing it...

Comment: @xaos_xv Please edit your question (using the edit link) instead of providing extra information in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
string = """Data
2017-10-12


Nr lekcji
6


Nauczyciel
Name Nothing


Rodzaj
sprawdzian


Przedmiot
Math


Opis
This is just a test.


Data dodania

                                        2017-10-01 18:12:31  """

# Clean the input data by splitting by row and removing blanks
clean = [i.strip() for i in string.split("\n") if i]

# Assume the data is in pairs and group them in key,pair by using index
# and index+1 in [0,2,4,6...]
d = {clean[ind]:clean[ind+1] for ind in range(0,len(clean),2)}

print(d)
```

Returns:

```
{'Data': '2017-10-12',
 'Data dodania': '2017-10-01 18:12:31',
 'Nauczyciel': 'Name Nothing',
 'Nr lekcji': '6',
 'Opis': 'This is just a test.',
 'Przedmiot': 'Math',
 'Rodzaj': 'sprawdzian'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to create a dictionary from your raw text:

```
# Defined multiline variable with your raw datat
text  = """Data
2017-10-12


Nr lekcji
6


Nauczyciel
Name Nothing


Rodzaj
sprawdzian


Przedmiot
Math


Opis
This is just a test.


Data dodania

                                    2017-10-01 18:12:31    """

# Clean the data to strip empty lines and unnecessary spaces
cleaned = [line.strip() for line in text.split('\n') if line.strip() != '']

# Create a dictionary from the stripped list where the value of each key is 
# the item in the list which comes after the key
myDict = dict(zip(cleaned[0::2], cleaned[1::2]))
```

And the result is:

```
>>> myDict 
{'Nr lekcji': '6',
'Nauczyciel': 'Name Nothing', 
'Przedmiot': 'Math', 
'Rodzaj': 'sprawdzian', 
'Opis': 'This is just a test.', 
'Data': '2017-10-12', 
'Data dodania': '2017-10-01 18:12:31'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not a clean solution, but might be useful.

```
with open('file.txt') as myfile:
    lines  = map(lambda e: e.strip(), filter(lambda e: len(e) > 0, myfile.read().split('\n')))
    # or in 3 lines
    # raw_lines = myfile.read().split('\n')
    # nonzero_length_lines = filter(lambda e: len(e) > 0, raw_lines)
    # lines = map(lambda e: e.strip(), nonzero_length_lines)
    h = {}
    i = 0
    while i<len(lines)-1:
        h[lines[i]] = lines[i+1]
        i+=2
    print(h)
```

https://repl.it/MeO5